# How to construct a holomorphic map between two complex tori?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $g>s$ be positive integers.
My question is how can I construct a holomorphic map from a complex tours of dimension $g$ to a torus of dimension $s$? For simplicity, let's assume $g=2$ and $s=1$.

To be exact, let $\Gamma$ be a lattice in $\mathbb{C}^2$ which is generated by $4$ elements. Fix this $\Gamma$ , we have chosen a complex torus $\mathbb{C}^2/\Gamma$ whose dimension is $2$.
I want to find a holomorphic map from $\mathbb{C}^2/\Gamma$ to $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ for some $\Lambda$. For the convenience of construction, $\Lambda$ may be chosen suitablely (probably according to $\Gamma$) here.

I think I should consider a holomorphic map $f:\mathbb{C}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(p+\Gamma) \subset f(p) + \Lambda$ for any $p \in \mathbb{C}^2.$ But I haven't found such an example yet for general $\Gamma.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean nonconstant holomorphic maps. In that case the result you ask about is not true. There exist $\Gamma$ such that there exist no nonconstant maps from $\mathbb C^2/\Gamma$ to $\mathbb C$. Since meromophic maps exist on any $1$-dimensional torus, this implies there cannot be any nonconstant holomorphic map $\mathbb C^2/\Gamma\to\mathbb C/\Lambda$ for any lattice $\Lambda$.

Existence of such $\Gamma$ is a result due to Siegel, and is in his *Analytic Functions of Several Complex Variables*. You can find discussion of this and many related results in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.07611).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: xyh — you mean "torus", not "tours". But surely it is easy to find a (2D complex) torus that double covers the one you want to be the codomain.

Comment: ... Just take one of the basis vectors and double it to get — along with the other basis vectors — a basis for a sublattice of  of index 2, giving a quotient torus that double covers the first one. Since holomorphy is a local property, and since this double cover is locally the same as the identity map was before, the double covering projection is also holomorphic.